# In Android Studio, why do I have to click 'run app' twice in the emulator to start the app?

Tags: android, android-studio, ms-android-emulator

In Android Studio, when I press play button to install and run the app on the Android Emulator, after about 5-10 seconds, I get a message on the bottom of the screen saying "Install successful" but the app doesn't actually run on the emulator, I have to press the play button again. This is quite frustrating because I have worked on projects where I just press play once and it installs and runs at the same time.

I tried searching this forum but couldn't find an answer. Does anybody else experience this and how do you fix it?

Comment: This issue started happening to me once I updated to Android Studio `4.1.1` -- it wasn't an issue on the previous version `3.6.1` -- it's frustrating :(

Comment: Yup. Same problem. Getting tired of this. Can't seem to find a solution anywhere. It's been several weeks dealing with this, and it's majorly slowing down my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Looks like the 'Run on Multiple Devices' option has been removed from the latest Android Studio update. The problem has started again and I can't seem to find a workaround or a solution.

--

Outdated solution:

Instead of clicking on the icon, I started using the dropdown box, clicking on 'Run on Multiple Devices', selecting the devices and clicking 'Run'.

This seems to have solved the problem for now.

[image: Select Run on Multiple Devices, select the devices and click Run]

[image: emul]