# Why do I have to click on Run 'app' twice to apply the latest changes

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I saw that there is a question which is the same of my issue, this is [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64970482/8139353), but I want to add more details.

In the first run I wrote in the xml row

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    ......
    android:text='@{model.type + model.points + " test 1 " + @string/points}'
    ...... />
```

While the run gives me:
[image: Image of the run number 1]

And in the second run you can see that **" test 1 "** is working in the image bellow:
[image: Image of the run number 2]

Thanks for helping

Comment: it's the voodoo

Comment: What is that?!! @UrielFrankel